# Different Loss functions on different segments of a DNN

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, keras, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

Is it possible to have different loss-functions defined on different "segments" of a deep network (in the following sense):

Suppose that I have some input-output pairs (x_n,y_n) and (x_n,z_n) and I want to train a deep network of the from f_k∘...∘f_1 (each f_i is a feed-forward layer) such that

- MSE(f_k∘...∘f_1(x_n) - y_n) is minimized
- MSE(f_k∘f_k-1(x_n) - z_n) is also minimized.

---

**Analogy/ Example/ Intuition/ Motivation:**

Suppose I want the output of my network to *approximately be like x^2* then f_k∘f_k-1(x_n)~~ x_n^2 and z_n:= x_n^2.  Then f_k∘...∘f_1(x_n)  a feed-forward network whose output layer is approximately the function x^2.

---

How can you do this in TensorFlow/Keras?

Comment: with f_n∘f_n-1(x_n) do u mean the output of the network / the final predictions?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Exactly.  I added an example to help clarify my end-goal

Comment: Does `_n` for `x_n, y_n, z_n` represent sample index?  Also `_n` for `f_n` represents layer number?  If so using the same letter is a bit confusing.

Comment: @KotaMori Good point, I modified the notation to make it cleaner but yes you are correct.

Comment: if u use the same loss function (MSE) for both the output u don't need to do anything. u can only define the loss_weight for the 2 output if u are interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by defining a two output model.
It essentially minimizes the weighted average of the two losses.

A restriction is that the input shape of the first and (n-1)-th layers must be same, since both receives the same input `x`.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input

input_shape = (1,)
model1 = Sequential([
    Dense(5, activation="relu", input_shape=input_shape),
    Dense(8, activation="relu"),
    Dense(input_shape[0])
])

model2 = Sequential([
    Dense(15, activation="relu", input_shape=input_shape),
    Dense(1)
])

x = Input(input_shape)
y = model2(model1(x))
z = model2(x)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=[y, z])
model.compile("adam", "mean_squared_error", loss_weight=[0.5, 0.5])

import numpy as np
n = 1000
x = np.random.normal(size=n * input_shape[0]).reshape((n, input_shape[0]))
y = x**2
z = x**2

history = model.fit(x, [y, z], epochs=100)
```

Visualization:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(history.history["loss"])

yhat, zhat = model.predict(x)
plt.scatter(x, yhat)
plt.scatter(x, zhat)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: How can I make it to only report the test-set error on the "y" data and not on the"z" data?

Comment: Make test set and provide to `model.fit`.  Then in the history, you should see each loss separately as well as the total loss.  I don't know how to suppress one of them.

Comment: Everything works great but it seems to be incompatible with RandomizedSearchCV is this normal?

Comment: If you are talking about `RandomSearchCV` from `sklearn` library, it should not become incompatible because your model has multiple outputs.  If any, it is a general problem 
 of how you use it with tensorflow models.  Anyways, that's a separate problem and you should open a new question if you cannot figure out.